# How to use JSON Query Array in Big Query Where Clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I   have BQ  Dataset  Table that has Data in JSON &  JSON_ARRAY formats , I need to filter for the row count that satisfy the columns present in  Conversation Signals which is of JSON Format.

BQ SQL :-

```
SELECT
   JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(conversation_signals, '$.turnSignals.noUserInput') AS No_User_Input,
   JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(conversation_signals, '$.turnSignals.webhookStatuses') AS webhook_status_0
 FROM 

`gcp-bq.dev_dataset.bq_export_data`
where    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(conversation_signals, '$.turnSignals.noUserInput') = 'true'

I need to add condition along with above Where clause to check for the below values for the Webhook Statuses which of the Array format 
Listed values to filter 

No_User_Input   webhook_status_0
TRUE        ["OK"]
TRUE        ["OK","OK"]
TRUE            ["OK","OK","OK"]
```

Please note that i have tried using UNNEST option too but still comparision "=" is not working. Please help me on how to add this set of conditions in the array set.

Please note that i have tried using UNNEST option too but still comparision "=" is not working. Please help me on how to add this set of conditions in the array set.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add some simple data

Comment: Hi @SelVazi  This is what the simple data i have , trying from my end for the solution .